# Need to customize a function in Model/Sitemap in Magento-2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I need to customize the function `_getStoreBaseUrl()` from the core file `magento\module-sitemap\Model\Sitemap.php`.

I have tried to override the Model file using preference method and also tried to implement Plugin, but it's throwing error when I write a constructor method in it.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isExist() on null in \vendor\magento\module-sitemap\Model\Sitemap.php:351 Stack trace: #0 \vendor\magento\framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb.php(406): Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap->beforeSave() #1 \vendor\magento\framework\Model\AbstractModel.php(647): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save(Object(Vendor\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap)) #2   \vendor\magento\module-sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\Sitemap\Save.php(84): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save() #3   \vendor\magento\module-sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\Sitemap\Save.php(150): Magento\Sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\Sitemap\Save->saveData(Array) #4   \generated\code\Magento\Sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\Sitemap\Save\Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\Sitemap\Save->execute() #5   \vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php(107): Magent in   \vendor\magento\module-sitemap\Model\Sitemap.php on line 351
```

I need to use the dependency injection way in this overrided file to get some custom values from the ScopeConfig.

My Model file is,

[image]

My di.xml is,

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: Can you please update your di.xml and model code in question?

Comment: yes,  I have updated the post.

Comment: actually you have used constructor so please use this too  \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem, \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Reader\Source\Deployed\DocumentRoot $documentRoot = null and   $this->_directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite($documentRoot->getPath()); inside your constructor

Answer (score 1):

Your construct should be like below:

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
    \Magento\Sitemap\Helper\Data $sitemapData,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Catalog\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Sitemap\Model\ResourceModel\Cms\PageFactory $cmsFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $modelDate,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime $dateTime,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    array $data = [],
    \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Reader\Source\Deployed\DocumentRoot $documentRoot = null
) {
    $this->_escaper = $escaper;
    $this->_sitemapData = $sitemapData;
    $documentRoot = $documentRoot ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(DocumentRoot::class);
    $this->_directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite($documentRoot->getPath());
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->_cmsFactory = $cmsFactory;
    $this->_dateModel = $modelDate;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_request = $request;
    $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

    parent::__construct($context, $registry,$escaper, $sitemapData,$filesystem,$categoryFactory,$productFactory,$cmsFactory,$modelDate,$storeManager,$request,$dateTime,$resource,$resourceCollection,$data,$documentRoot);
}
```

Comment: Then it's throwing error as   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb in  \vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php:111

Comment: I have tried all these ways, but not working

Comment: Check removing from parent::constuct resource and resourceConnection and check @MGento

Comment: still, same error.

Comment: still same issue facing if any one know reply me

Answer (score 0):

Add in your constructor below code too

```
use Magento\Config\Model\Config\Reader\Source\Deployed\DocumentRoot;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Robots\Model\Config\Value;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

     public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Reader\Source\Deployed\DocumentRoot $documentRoot = null

) {
    $documentRoot = $documentRoot ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(DocumentRoot::class);
    $this->_directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite($documentRoot->getPath());
    $this->scopeConfig=$scopeConfig;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it won't work even if I add those in my constructor .

Comment: what is error now ? i think you should copy complete constructor and add your new dependency also on that constructor.

Comment: I have updated code

Comment: Tried all these ways already but not working. I also tried the plugin way too. The above way gives error like  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb in  \vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php:111

Comment: can you use constructor like that only and check ?

Comment: yes, did, still  getting the same error, Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb ...